# Manga about a witch who was reincarnated as her previous enemy's niece after being killed by her subordinate

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, witches

It is the story of a witch who was killed by her beloved subordinate and then reincarnated in a duke's family as the niece of her sworn enemy. That duke's family is particularly skilled in swordsmanship and they hated magic. The witch was born as a grand duke's granddaughter and tried to run away from home.

She tried to run away several times, but was caught immediately and dropped that idea after she nearly became part of human trafficking, so she decided to run away when she gets her powers back. And in the meantime, she grew a little closer with her uncle, the future duke, and he adopted her and gave her the family name.

I forget to mention that both of her biological parents were dead by the time she was born and the grand duke (her grandfather) and future duke both came to know eventually that she possessed magical powers and still accepted her. And, as far as I know, she became the owner of a crown which is an artifact.

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Comment: No i don't but she have short hairs i remember that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Gimme That Pacifier!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/7avaqyn/gimme-that-pacifier)***...?

> Betrayed and executed by her pupil, magician Hela Sylopia is reborn as the neglected infant granddaughter of a rivaling nation's duke. To make matters worse, her family doesn't remember her name, and the maids don't care what happens to her! But when she discovers that having her pacifier in her mouth can expand her mind, Hela uses that to her advantage to survive, get rid of those who stand in her way, and start plotting her revenge. Will Hela succeed, or will she wish she'd never been reborn?

Hela Sylopia, the head of a magic tower, was accused of practicing dark magic by her former pupil, the High Priest, Melane, and subsequently executed.

She then wakes up in the body of Shelina, the ten-month-old granddaughter of Duke Deschar Klaune, and the niece of his son and heir, Charente, whom she regards as a cold-blooded maniac, having known both both him and Deschar in her previous life. Her father, Charente's younger brother, Balian, has recently passed away, and her mother, a commoner, is either dead as well or otherwise out of the picture. Charente's young son, Kaishan, is also a member of the household.

The Klaunes are a family of distinguished swordsmen, and Charente in particular dislikes magic. Both Deschar and Charente are initially cold towards Shelina, but warm up to her over time, despite learning of her magical abilities, which are weaker in her new body.

> [image: "Gimme That Pacifier!," chapter 29, page 16-18.]

Shelina repeatedly tries to run away from the Klaune household, but keeps getting caught. Then, in chapter 40, when she's three years old, she teleports herself to an orphanage, but it turns out that they traffic children there, and Charente comes to rescue her.

In chapter 56, the Ruler's Crown, a magical artefact found in some old ruins, chooses her as its owner.

> [image: "Gimme That Pacifier!," chapter 57, page 47-49.]

Comment: Yes,This is tq for informing